# Is there any way to Find similar words one below another in 2 lines

Tags: unix, vim, notepad++, vi

We have a large file in unix/windows.
The data in it is like

```
update table tblName set col1='Test' where col1='Test1'
select * from a
select * from b
delete from tblName where col1='xyz'
select * from a
select * from b
select * from c
delete from tblName where col1='pqr'
select * from c
```

I want to search all the lines where 2 or more select statements appears one below another in VI or Notepad++ and any other editor.

E.g.

Search should find

```
select * from a
select * from b
```

Or even

```
select * from a
select * from b
select * from c
```

but not

```
select * from c (the last line)
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `(^select \* from.*\R)(?1)+`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Find next</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(                   # start group 1
    ^               # beginning of line
    select \* from  # literally
    .*              # 0 or more any character but newline
    \R              # any kind of linebreak (ie. \r, \n, \r\n)
)                   # end group 1
(?1)+               # repeat pattern defined in group 1, 1 or more times
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into regular expressions for that. You should check which standard your text editor uses, you will find that in the documentation ([Notepad++](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions), [vim](http://vimregex.com)) On vim, you can also do :help pattern to find documentation about this. In most text editors, this regex should work:

```
(select \* from \w+\n){2,}
```

It matches two or more lines in succesion that are in the form

```
select * from (some variable made up of letters, numbers and underscores)
```

It will *not* match

```
select * from a where property = "foo"
```

In vim, things are slightly different, you will have to use the pattern

```
\(select \* from \w\+\n\)\{2,\}
```

so then you can do things like replacing those lines

```
:%s/\(select \* from \w\+\n\)\{2,\}/hey, two or more select statements were removed here\r/g
```

(be careful though, those lines will be replaced in the whole file, so check what you will be losing).

There are also more details that you might want to consider, for instance case-sensitive vs. case-insensitive search and empty lines.